# Saving a PDF file with Photoshop CS 3 gives error because of the font I use?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, pdf

I'm trying to save a PDF file and retain text,
The problem is that when I use some hebrew fonts that I purchased I get an error while saving the file,
The error is the famous: "Could not save as 'untitiled.pdf' because of a program error."

I insist to use those fonts, I just don't know why they're causing that error.
I tried to use font forge to re-generate the font with different settings, nothing seemed to solve the issue though.

I'd love to know how to solve this problem,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There most likely is no ideal solution.

Some fonts do not permit embedding within PDFs. And some fonts are constructed so poorly, they will cause errors inherently.

- You can try converting the type layers to shape layers and then saving as a PDF.
- You can try rasterizing the type layers, then saving as a PDF.

Those are pretty much your only two options.

Comment: I was afraid of an answer like that, haha I knew that these are two options I could use but wanted to avoid them. Do you have any idea if moving to InDesign will solve the issue? or are there problems there with fonts as well?

Comment: If the issue is the font, then it will be an issue anywhere a PDF is generated. Moving to Indesign may not improve anything.

Comment: It actually did solve the issue, seems like Photoshop is a bit too picky when it comes to fonts, anyhow thanks for answering!

Comment: Aren't there any plugins for for PDF reader (or Acrobat) character sets such as the Hebrew one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a copy of your working file- you can do so and then go to Edit- Flatten Image.

This will prevent you from making changes to that version of your file, but that should allow you to make a PDF of the image/text. You can then work off of the original and do the same process when you want to print to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

**1) Flattening the layers and exporting your PDF.**

This is not the ideal solution because of the loss of quality.

**2) You can try to open your .psd files with the layers in Illustrator**

See if your fonts show properly. If they do, go on the menu "Type" in Illustrator and select "create outline". Your fonts will become graphics of perfect quality. Then you can simply export your PDF from Illustrator.

See this how-to:  [How to convert text layers in Photoshop to vector in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55345/how-to-keep-the-text-in-vector-in-photoshop-without-rasterizing-it-or-flattening)

If you still get some error message after this, your problem is not related to the fonts.